# Symfony 2 compass with assetic on Windows XP

Tags: ruby, symfony, sass, assetic

I try to install Compass in my Symfony 2.3.1 project on Windows XP though not successfuly up to now.
I have Ruby, compass, sass the newest versions installed.

This is my assetic configuration in **app/config/config.yml**

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    #bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        sass:    ~
        compass: ~
```

Here is my **app/cofnfig/parameters.xml**

```
# Assetic
    assetic.filter.compass.images_dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/images
    assetic.filter.compass.http_path:  /images
    assetic.filter.compass.bin: C:/Ruby200/bin/compass
```

The block code including stylesheets section in **app/Resources/views/base.html.twig**

```
{% stylesheets filter="compass"
            "@PortalSlubnyMainBundle/Resources/assets/css/main.sass"
            "@PortalSlubnyMainBundle/Resources/assets/css/header.sass"
            "@PortalSlubnyMainBundle/Resources/assets/css/footer.sass"
        %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
        {% endstylesheets %}
```

Ok so when I try to compile this from command line as a result of this command **php app/console assetic:dump** I get output below:

> Dumping all dev assets. Debug mode is on.
>
> 17:46:14 [file+] C:/xampp/htdocs/slub/app/../web/css/12c97a7.css
>
> [Assetic\Exception\FilterException]   An error occurred while
>   running:   "C:\Ruby200\bin\ruby.EXE" "C:/Ruby200/bin/compass"
>   "compile" "C:\Documents   and Settings\piotr\Ustawienia lokalne\Temp"
>   "--images-dir" "C:/xampp/htdocs   /slub/app/../web/images" "--config"
>   "C:\Documents and Settings\piotr\Ustawi   enia
>   lokalne\Temp\ass1C9.tmp" "--sass-dir"  "--css-dir"  "C:/Documents and 
>   Settings/piotr/Ustawienia lokalne/Temp/ass1CA.tmp.sass"
>
> Error Output:   You must compile individual stylesheets from the
>   project directory.
>
> Input:   html, body {
>           overflow-x: hidden;
>
> ```
>     background-color: yellow;
> ```
>
> }
>
> assetic:dump [--watch] [--force] [--period="..."] [write_to]

Ruby is working from cmd and it is set in the PATH environment variable as well as compass. Guys any help would be fully apreciated.

**EDIT:**
Thanks for the answer unfortunetly it doesnt help me either.

1. When I changed names to bundles/portalslubnymain/css/main.sass CLI return me error sth similar to **that this file is unable to find**, thogh the paths to files seem to be ok
2. I followed instructions form the article you posted earlier I also checked this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626777/how-to-have-assetic-sass-work-with-symfony2-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code i suggest you followed this [article](http://alexandre-salome.fr/blog/Sass-Compass-Assetic-In-Ten-Minutes). please notice the UPDATE notice at the end!

At first your assets should live in the **Resources/public** folder ...

... not in Resources/assets. fix this...

Afterwards please change ...

```
{% stylesheets filter="compass"
        "@PortalSlubnyMainBundle/Resources/public/css/main.sass"
        "@PortalSlubnyMainBundle/Resources/public/css/header.sass"
        "@PortalSlubnyMainBundle/Resources/public/css/footer.sass"
```

... to

```
{% stylesheets filter="compass"
    "bundles/portalslubnymain/css/main.sass"
    "bundles/portalslubnymain/css/header.sass"
    "bundles/portalslubnymain/css/footer.sass"
```

... because some assetic filters ( i.e. cssrewrite ) are known to NOT work with the @-syntax.

Afterwards symlink your assets into the web dir like this:

```
app/console assets:install web --symlink
```

Finally you should be able to run

```
app/console assetic:dump
```