# Assetic generating empty files (symfony2 + less) on Windows

Tags: windows, symfony, less, assetic

I recently introduced Bootstrap + LessCSS in my Symfony2 installation.

I'm using Assetic for assets management, with some filters: cssrewrite, yui_css, yui_js

I was able to add the less filer with no pain on my Ubuntu machine and on a SUSE Linux server, but after setting up everything on some Windows 7 machines used by my colleagues, we're only getting empty files as output.

I've already walked through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195114/symfony2-assetics-yui-compressor-on-windows-path-syntax) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622960/how-to-use-scss-filter-in-symfony2-under-windows/9658410#9658410), but nothing seems to work with 'less'.

Please note that lessc command is working just fine if called from command line.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in Symfony 2.4 thanks to https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/8067