# Symfony2 fatal error You have requested a non-existent parameter java_path

Tags: php, symfony

im working in SmFony Project but i got some issues when i would get access on my poject via this URL : `http://localhost/oksa-depannage/web/app_dev.php/login`

"OKSA-DEPANNAGE" is a project name.

So i hope that my question is clear

Errors :

```
  in C:\wamp\www\oksa-depannage\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBag.php line 106
at ParameterBag->get('java_path') in C:\wamp\www\oksa-depannage\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBag.php line 232
at ParameterBag->resolveString('%java_path%', array()) in C:\wamp\www\oksa-depannage\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBag.php line 203
at ParameterBag->resolveValue('%java_path%', array()) in C:\wamp\www\oksa-depannage\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBag.php line 193
at ParameterBag->resolveValue(array('debug' => '%kernel.debug%', 'use_controller' => false, 'bundles' => array('OksaTemplateBundle'), 'java' => '%java_path%', 'filters' => array('cssrewrite' => null, 'yui_css' => array('jar' => '%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar'), 'yui_js' => array('jar' => '%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar'))), array()) in C:\wamp\www\oksa-depannage\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBag.php line 193
at ParameterBag->resolveValue(array(array('debug' => '%kernel.debug%', 'use_controller' => false, 'bundles' => array('OksaTemplateBundle'), 'java' => '%java_path%', 'filters' => array('cssrewrite' => null, 'yui_css' => array('jar' => '%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar'), 'yui_js' => array('jar' => '%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar'))), array('use_controller' => true))) in C:\wamp\www\oksa-depannage\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php line 44
at MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in C:\wamp\www\oksa-depannage\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php line 39
at MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in C:\wamp\www\oksa-depannage\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler.php line 117
at Compiler->compile(object(ContainerBuilder)) in C:\wamp\www\oksa-depannage\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder.php line 619
at ContainerBuilder->compile() in C:\wamp\www\oksa-depannage\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2491
at Kernel->initializeContainer() in C:\wamp\www\oksa-depannage\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2270
at Kernel->boot() in C:\wamp\www\oksa-depannage\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2301
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in C:\wamp\www\oksa-depannage\web\app_dev.php line 28
```

thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like symfony is trying to start the yui compressor, which is a java library.

This post has a workaround to make this situation work on windows: [symfony2 assetics yui compressor on windows (path syntax)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195114/symfony2-assetics-yui-compressor-on-windows-path-syntax)

Comment: what is means "yui compressor" ?!